# Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am getting the following error in my Sheets Add-on:

```
Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch
```

I'm aware of the limits [here](https://docs.google.com/a/macros/seekwell.io/dashboard), but how can I tell if I am hitting the "URLFetch calls" of 100,000 or the "URLFetch data received" of 100mB? They are two very different issues and if I'm hitting the first one, I must be making requests unintentionally somewhere because there's no way I'm intentionally making the call 100k times a day. It is possible I'm hitting the 100mb, but the way the error is phrased makes me think I'm hitting the first, is there anyway to know for sure which one I'm hitting?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into that too. I only have 1000 rows going out to a web service. Data did not change neither in my sheet nor in the service. But at some point today most of my cells show #Error with this cause.

I feel like it's going out to re-fetch the results way too often. Is there not some caching that can be employed?

---

UPDATE (long time due): adding cache was exactly what was needed. So I implemented a function `fetch(url)` which uses a cache and that way avoids the replicate calls.

```
function fetch(url) {
  var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  var result = cache.get(url);
  if(!result) {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    result = response.getContentText();
    cache.put(url, result, 21600);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You currently can not do it.

Perhaps run a counter in your script.