# Why are my project quotas not being displayed?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-sheets-api

We are trying to find solutions for the `Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch` exception that our Google Sheets custom function keeps throwing (many users across the world).

Following this guide:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#requesting_higher_quota

We navigate to our quota page and there is no usage being reported? The project is connected correctly as our error dashboard is full. My profile also has full super user access for each role.

The `urlFetch` quota doesn't even appear if I enter it in the search???

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the functions in the error message or at least one of them per question.  If you are transfering data in a loop trying slowing down the loop.

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62805656/exception-service-invoked-too-many-times-for-one-day-urlfetch) might help you, try to implement the [cache service] (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service)

Comment: It has nothing to do with looping, we have this service being used by thousands of users across the world. We have also built a caching mechanism @Cooper

Answer (score 1):

In the future you should not ask two questions in the same question. If you had just asked about the error we could have just linked to the duplicate question. Please see my answer to both of your questions.

## question one

> Why are my project quotas not being displayed?

To answer your question:

Google APis quotas are available on [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard)  Its not the same system as Google Cloud console.

Under library search for sheets -> click Manage -> on the right there is a menu called quota.

[image]

## question two

> We are trying to find solutions for the Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch exception that our Google Sheets custom function keeps throwing (many users across the world).

To answer your second question please see [Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62813073/1841839)

> You can implement CacheService and PropertiesService together and only retrieve the URL again after a specified amount of time.

Comment: I don't even have that Library enabled? There is no manage button